# Is there a way to add a sort of "custom tags" and filter by them in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a table with a bunch of people in rows. On the columns are the skills that they have. There's a bunch of them.

Now all the people there work in different departments, sales, store, CS and etc. Some of them though work on several positions. There is no column for this.

What I need is a way to apply a filter that will give me all the people working in Sales department for example, but without a column there I can't use normal filter.

Is there a way that I can tag a row with say "Sales" tag and then filter the people having that tag? I would also like to add multiple tags to people not just one as they can work in different departments.

Comment: Just create a new column and the info for each person.  When you filter on it, filter for text -> contains "sales" (or whatever tag you want to filter for)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using columns for some reason. But I like the idea. So just do like sales, CS, store and etc in one column (in case there's no other way?)

Comment: Yeah, that would work just fine.

Comment: Adding the column(s) (1 column for each department, I think) is by far the easiest, most user-friendly way of doing this. There's no way to add a "tag" to an individual cell (or range). You could add a `.NoteText` property to each cell, but that seems clumsy, and you'd have to use VBA to filter (hide/unhide) the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column, but `hide it` (right-clink on **its header** and select `Hide`).